# Is the anti-derivative of $f'(x) = f(x)$ OR $f(x) + C$

Tags: integration

Pretty straightforward question from the title. What is the anti-derivative of $f'(x)$? In my head it makes sense for it to be $f(x) + C$ since I can take the derivative of that and get back to where I started, I however noticed in Khan Academy's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUUPP70Fhpo&feature=youtu.be&t=7m57s) that he claims it's $f(x)$

Comment: One speaks of "an" antiderivative, not "the" antiderivative. Note that $f(x)$ is a special case of $f(x)+C$, with $C=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Both $f(x)$ and $f(x)+c$, for any constant $c$, are anti-derivatives for $f'(x)$. If an anti-derivative exists, it is not unique, and there are infinitely many anti-derivatives which differ from one another by a constant.

---

What's important to note is that, given a real function $g$, an anti-derivative for $g$ is *any* real function $G$ which satisfies $G'=g$.
It follows immediately from the definition that if $G$ is an anti-derivative for $g$, then so is $G+c$.

On the other hand, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are anti-derivatives for $g$, then we have

$$(G_1-G_2)'=G_1'-G_2'=g'-g'=0,$$

so that $G_1-G_2$ is constant.
In other words, if you find an anti-derivative $G$ for $g$, any other anti-derivative for $g$ is of the form $G+c$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not unique, and is equal to $f(x)+c$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, when $c=0$, you return $f(x)$ as *an* anti-derivative

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $F:A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f:B \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that $F'(x)=f(x)$. A anti-derivative of $f$ is any function of the form $$\int f(x)dx=F(x)+C, \: \mathrm{where} \: C \in \mathbb{R}.$$ The constant $C$ is called the *constant of integration*. You can see that the number of anti-derivatives of a function is infinite, furthermore that number is equal to $|\mathbb{R}|$ (the cardinality of the set of real numbers). This makes sense because $$\frac{d}{dx}[F(x)+C]=\frac{d}{dx}[F(x)]+\dfrac{d}{dx}[C]=F'(x)+0=f(x).$$

In particular, you can set $C=0$ and say that $f$ is **a** antiderivative of $F$ (of course, it isn't unique).